# Time multiple commands without a subshell?

Tags: time, zsh, subshell

Is there a way to use the `time` reserved word in zsh to time multiple commands, without starting a subshell?

I know that this works:

```
{ time (
    sleep 5
    sleep 3
    PROMPT='foobar> '
) }
```

However the parentheses mean that a subshell is created, and variables initialized don't get exported.

I know I can capture the variables before and after, like

```
start=$(time)
# do something
end=$(time)
echo start - end | bc
```

Though for ad hoc timing this is a little cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `time` can only work on a different process. So, it won't work with `{ ... }` or with a builtin, like:

```
time { ls }
time echo
```

Note that your method capturing the `time` output won't work if there are already children (as their times when running the commands will also be taken into account). Ditto if you have traps and corresponding signals occur.